# cover kafka consumer lag

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using `Spring @kafkaListener` in my application. Currently I have only one partition and two `instances` running of my application. Producer is constantly producing messages on topic, my application is consuming those messages, doing some processing on consumed messages and publishing on another `topic`.

I am checking `consumer lag` from kafka and there is huge lag for consumer. My question is how can I fill or cover the consumer lag so there will minimal lag.

Below is my consumer config -

```
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST.name().toLowerCase());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);


   factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
```

Spring Boot Version : 2.1.8

Comment: You cant have more instances than partitions. Just let it run

Comment: @ppb are you manually committing the offset?

Comment: You can improve performance only if you distribute records between different partitions. Then your different instances will be in work. Otherwise you only can have a thread shifting in your listener, but this way you may lose data on crash

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I will increase the partitions to distribute the records, any suggestions how many partitions I can make for 250K messages per seconds. Currently I am consuming single record and processing it. Does any differences make in performance if I consume messages in batch?

Comment: No, because essentially the batch comes from consumer poll and per-record we just iterate that batch. You may consider to commit offset per batch though. That would improve performance